# C# calling events from another class .Net Framework

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am trying to call an event from a class I have in a separate file called Placeholder.cs in .NetFramework.

I have a textbox called `Username_TextBox` that I want to call the events from.  I'm not sure whether I need to create an Event Handler or a method to be able to do this. I have tried creating a new instance of the class I want to reference the event from, but I don't know how to assign or reference it to the `Username_TextBox`.

Comment: You don't call events, you subscribe to them. Its actually, to put it in your terms, the event who calls you (or more technically, any subscribed event handlers).

Comment: Some code will be helpful. `Username_TextBox` is your custom class?

Comment: First of all, please read, [how to ask a good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You could also google for how to use events and find something like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable) or [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ashush/events-in-C-Sharp/) and then should you have any questions post your question here providing an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustating your problem.

Comment: Hi @Fabjan, I do apologise for the vagueness of the question, but I've been on to numerous posts on here and can't seem to find the right fit.  I am new to C# so please bear with me.  I understand that you need to subscribe to an event but I am not sure how to go about it when assigning it to a button in .Net.  The events I want to subscribe to make the initial text in the textbox disappear when you focus or click on it.  I would provide some code but I do not know if I need to subscribe using a method or an event handler in this context?  Different posts suggest different answers.

Comment: @kehoewex86 You could create a simple console application and your own event `MyEvent` with eventhandler `MyEventHandler`, then subscribe eventhandler to event to understand how it work. In other part of code invoke the event.

Answer (score 0):

From one of your comments it sounds like you have a `Textbox` that has some text in it and when the `Textbox` has focus, you wish for that text to be removed?

If I am understanding your comment, then the code below may help you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);

    private const uint EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;
    private const uint CB_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1703;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Text that will appear in the textbox if it is empty
        setCueText(textBox1, "Enter password here");
    }


    private void setCueText(Control ctl, string text)
    {
        if (ctl is ComboBox)
        {
            SendMessage(ctl.Handle, CB_SETCUEBANNER, (IntPtr)0, text);
        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(ctl.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, (IntPtr)0, text);
        }
    }

}
```